# Uniqueness of Jordan-Chevalley decompostion

Tags: linear-transformations, proof-explanation

I've read the proof of existence and uniqueness of Jordan Chevalley decompostion (from Humphrey's book -Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation theory), and I didn't quite get the uniqueness part. it  was based on the claim:

If $x,y$ are commuting semi-simple operators, then $x+y$ semi simple.

(The definition of semi-simple that was given in the book was: $x \in V$, ($dimV< \infty$) is called semi-simple if its minimal polynomial over $F$ are all distinct, or equivalently ($F$ being algebraically closed) $x$ is semi simple if and only if $x$ is diagonalizable.)

I tried to prove this but couldn't, can somebody give me an explanation to why is this claim true? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If $x,y$ are diagonalizable and commutes, then there is a basis when both $x$ and $y$ are diagonal.

Comment: Hey @N.H. Thanks for replying. I understand that that's what the claim is saying, but is it trivial? It's not that clear to me. Thanks

Comment: I am cheating a bit, and assuming that any Lie algebra is a "concrete" Lie algebra, i.e $\mathfrak g \subset \mathfrak{gl}(W)$ for some vector space $W$. Maybe it's the definition of Humphrey but I'm not familiar with this book. Once you know this, $x,y$ becomes simply matrices and this is a linear algebra statement. 
For the proof, you can show that $x,y$ should share an eigenvector and use induction for show that $W = \sum_i W_i$ where $W_i$ is an eigenspace for both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @N.H. Thanks for the help. Humphrey didn't prove it but claimes that every lie algebra is isomorphic to a linear lie algebra so it's ok to assume that. I will try to do what you've suggested. Thanks!